# Save button states when changing mode in android

Tags: android

After clicking on a button (which starts a time intensive task in the background), I want to disable the button until the task is over and show a progressbar:

```
public void onConnect(final View view) {
    enableConnectButton(false);
    findViewById(R.id.connectProgress).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new ConnectTask().execute(ip, port);
}

private void enableConnectButton(boolean state) {
    Button connectButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.connectButton));
    connectButton.setEnabled(state);
}
```

Unfortunately when I change to landscape or portrait mode the UI state of the button and progressbar is not saved.

I thought that Android maintains widget states like disable or visibiliy when providing an id. What did I wrong?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/connectButton"
    android:text="@string/connectButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onConnect"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a device is rotated, Android automatically destroys and recreates the activity:

> Caution: Your activity will be destroyed and recreated each time the
>   user rotates the screen. When the screen changes orientation, the
>   system destroys and recreates the foreground activity because the
>   screen configuration has changed and your activity might need to load
>   alternative resources (such as the layout).

You will need to use the onSaveInstanceState(), onRestoreInstanceState() and onCreate() to save the status of the button and progress bar when the device is rotate, then reapply them after the rotation.

Here is Google's official documentation concerning this situation:

[Recreating An Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Comment: So, only text from a TextEdit and the scroll position will be saved automaticly, but the state of button won't?

Comment: That is correct. You will need to save this outside the activity and examine it when the activity is recreated.